# Bifrost is not detecting incoming transaction

Tags: bifrost

i have succesfully setup **bifrost** and **geth** on my pc. And now i'm trying to simulate ICO using bifrost-js-sdk [example.html](https://github.com/stellar/bifrost-js-sdk/blob/master/example.html), by sending some ropsten ETH to address provided. But it seems that there's no transaction detected by bifrost, is there something wrong with my configs ? thanks.

#### geth configuration

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --networkid 3 --testnet
```

#### bifrost configuration (bifrost.cfg)

```
port=8000
using_proxy=false
access-control-allow-origin-header="*"

[ethereum]
master_public_key="[SOME_MPK]"
rpc_server="localhost:8545"
network_id="3"
minimum_value_eth="0.00001"

[stellar]
issuer_public_key="[SOME_PUBLIC_KEY]"
signer_secret_key="[SOME_SECRET_KEY]"
token_asset_code="XXXX"
needs_authorize=false
horizon="https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org"
network_passphrase="Test SDF Network ; September 2015"

[database]
type="postgres"
dsn="postgres://user:secret@localhost:5432/bifrost?sslmode=disable"
```

Comment: To start, have you confirmed your geth setup is correct? Have you been able to receive tx's on ropsten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of possible reasons why this isn't working for you. The list is not complete, please provide more information that can help finding a real issue:

- Bifrost is detecting transactions but there's a proxy between client and Bifrost server and it's blocking SSE (Server-Sent Events) sent by Bifrost. Solution for this can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/801629).
- There's a long queue of blocks Bifrost needs to process. During the first start of Bifrost, it starts processing blocks from the latest block available. If Bifrost was turned off for a longer time or `geth` is still catchup up it may cause delays. To solve this, recreate Bifrost DB so it resets data or (if you don't want to delete data in a DB) set `ethereum_last_block` value in `key_value_store` table to `0`.
- You are sending a transaction with amount below `minimum_value_eth`.
- Geth is connected to one network and you're sending ETH in another network (this is probably not the case here, but I want to have as many reasons as possible in this answer).