# Bifrost not receiving events when connected to the Ropsten network

Tags: testnet, bifrost

I've setup bifrost to connect to the Ropsten network, but I'm not receiving transaction events in biforst--js-sdk application;

when I start geth with these parameters: `geth --rpc --networkid 3` and then run bifrost, I'm receiving such logs on bifrost:

`INFO[2018-06-18T13:19:22+03:00] Processing block                              blockNumber=3614631 blockTime=2017-04-28 13:35:07 +0300 EEST pid=18765 service=EthereumListener transactions=30
INFO[2018-06-18T13:19:22+03:00] Processed block                               blockNumber=3614631 blockTime=2017-04-28 13:35:07 +0300 EEST pid=18765 service=EthereumListener transactions=30
INFO[2018-06-18T13:19:23+03:00] Processing block                              blockNumber=3614632 blockTime=2017-04-28 13:35:23 +0300 EEST pid=18765 service=EthereumListener transactions=17
INFO[2018-06-18T13:19:23+03:00] Processed block                               blockNumber=3614632 blockTime=2017-04-28 13:35:23 +0300 EEST pid=18765 service=EthereumListener transactions=17`

I wanted geth to connect to the Ropsten network, but given block numbers say that geth is connected to the mainnet.

if I run geth with these parameters: `geth --rps --testnet --networkid 3`, logs on bifrost are:

`INFO[2018-06-18T14:29:47+03:00] Stats                                         pid=22177 service=StellarAccountConfigurator statuses=map[]
INFO[2018-06-18T14:30:02+03:00] Stats                                         pid=22177 service=StellarAccountConfigurator statuses=map[]
INFO[2018-06-18T14:30:17+03:00] Stats                                         pid=22177 service=StellarAccountConfigurator statuses=map[]
INFO[2018-06-18T14:30:32+03:00] Stats                                         pid=22177 service=StellarAccountConfigurator statuses=map[]`

geth logs:

`INFO [06-18|14:29:37] Imported new block headers               count=0    elapsed=3.647ms   number=862416 hash=7f747a…a48c83 ignored=192
INFO [06-18|14:29:38] Imported new block headers               count=0    elapsed=10.903ms  number=862608 hash=ac6b08…dacd8a ignored=192
INFO [06-18|14:29:38] Imported new block receipts              count=2    elapsed=15.960ms  number=862226 hash=99d6e4…fb8689 size=242.58kB ignored=0
INFO [06-18|14:29:39] Imported new block headers               count=0    elapsed=11.094ms  number=862800 hash=452210…1da907 ignored=192
INFO [06-18|14:29:39] Imported new block receipts              count=3    elapsed=10.072ms  number=862229 hash=9280b7…59efed size=364.31kB ignored=0
INFO [06-18|14:29:39] Imported new block headers               count=0    elapsed=13.814ms  number=862992 hash=089017…73f210 ignored=192
INFO [06-18|14:29:41] Imported new state entries               count=652  elapsed=4.585ms   processed=1258863 pending=1572  retry=0   duplicate=3 unexpected=24
INFO [06-18|14:29:45] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=2.637ms   processed=1259631 pending=1193  retry=0   duplicate=3 unexpected=24
WARN [06-18|14:29:48] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=94c15d1b9e2fe7ce err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
WARN [06-18|14:29:53] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=05d7d56d89ccfbf9 err="action from bad peer ignored"
WARN [06-18|14:30:30] Empty head header set                    peer=865a63255b3bb680
WARN [06-18|14:30:30] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=865a63255b3bb680 err="empty header set by peer"
WARN [06-18|14:31:01] Empty head header set                    peer=865a63255b3bb680
WARN [06-18|14:31:01] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=865a63255b3bb680 err="empty header set by peer"`

Is it correct behavior? Because in the second case bifrost not syncing block, only geth is importing blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to other issue [Bifrost is not detecting incoming transaction](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/807/bifrost-is-not-detecting-incoming-transaction?rq=1)

You have to import all ETH blocks

> There's a long queue of blocks Bifrost needs to process. During the
>   first start of Bifrost, it starts processing blocks from the latest
>   block available. If Bifrost was turned off for a longer time or geth
>   is still catchup up it may cause delays. To solve this, recreate
>   Bifrost DB so it resets data or (if you don't want to delete data in a
>   DB) set ethereum_last_block value in key_value_store table to 0.

It will take long time to improt/process all blocks, I had to change the ethereum_last_block value to start from the latest block no. Block 3461928 https://ropsten.etherscan.io/  and it worked with me.

You can use `--light` option, It does not need to import all ETH blocks. 
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26992/run-mist-without-downloading-blockchain

Comment: regardless the state of the Bifrost DB, geth must catch up the state and only then it will be able to handle transactions/events. is it right?

Comment: Yes, I did not import all blocks, and it worked with me.